# Dash output intermediary messages during callbacks

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using Dash for my UI and I am stuck with how I could **return custom messages to the UI, while a callback is running**.

More precisely, I am running a callback that takes in various inputs from the UI and outputs the downloaded and processes data to a Dash DataTable.

Downloading/ processing the data takes often long and I would like to **output messages about the status of the program** to the user **while the callback is running**. See the sample code below:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
     ...
     html.Div([ dcc.Loading(
                      id='ls-loading', children=[
                      #Output Loading message
                      html.P(id='loading-message'),
                      #Output Datatable when callback finishes
                      dash_table.DataTable(
                                          id= 'data-table',
                                          ...)
...])
])
               

@app.callback([Output('loading-message','data')
               Output('data-table','data')
               Output('data-table', 'columns'),
               [Input('button','n_clicks')],
               [State('date-selector', 'date'),
               ...])

def update_table(n_clicks, input1, input2,...)
    if n_clicks > 0:
       """
          Inside the get_data() function: return loading-message, dash.no_update,
           That is while the data is loading return loading-messages, 
            but in such a way that the callback function does not stop executing.              
       """
       data, columns = get_data()
       #If data is loaded return None for loading-message
       return None, data, columns
```

I know there is a **dcc.Interval** component in Dash that could help by being able to run the callback at some specified time intervals, but I want these messages to not be functions of time, but rather when some function in the program has been done.E.g. "Data has been loaded", "Doing Calculations...", etc.

I tried to search on Google and read through the documentation of Dash, but did not find anything useful on how to go about this.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You could use a background callback, which allows to display and update a [progress bar](https://dash.plotly.com/background-callbacks#example-4:-progress-bar) while the callback is running. Since you can use a graph as the "progress bar" component, it allows to display some text too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah, I was thinking of doing this, but I don't see how I can use this effectively if I don't want to output messages based on the state of progress, but rather, whether different functions run successfully. I was thinking of perhaps breaking down my big callback into multiple callbacks and linking them together while they also output some messages.